# how to refresh just table information after clicking a button in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting with ReactJS now. I have a table (isn't a React Component) and I need to refresh its information after clicking a button. These informations come from an array. I already exclude the informations from array, but i couldn't find a way to refresh the front end.

Here's the code:

```
function remove(e) {
    var array = impacts;
    var index = e.target.value;
    array.splice(index, 1);
    setImpacts(array);

    //??????
}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <select id="base">
                {bases.map(base => (
                    <option key={base._id}>{base.module}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <select id="impact">
                <option>CPU</option>
                <option>Memória</option>
                <option>Filesystem</option>
                <option>Tablespace</option>
            </select>

            <input type="number" id="qtdImpact" placeholder="Impacto" min="0" max="100" required />
            <div id="label">CORES</div>

            <input type="text" id="tbsfs" placeholder="Tablespace/Filesystem" />
            <button type="submit" value="adicionar">ADICIONAR</button>

        </form>

        <button type="button" value="gerar" onClick={generateGraph}>GERAR GRAFICOS</button>
        <div id="div-tabela">
            <table id="tabela">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>NOME DA BASE</td>
                        <td>MODULO</td>
                        <td>REMOVER</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        impacts.map((each, index) => (
                            <tr key={index}>
                                <td>{each.module}</td>
                                <td>{each.type}</td>
                                <td><button type="button" value={index} onClick={remove}>REMOVER</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    </div>
);
```

The **remove function** is where I'm removing the informations from array, and might be here that I need to refresh the front end.

Someone has any idea of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should keep your array in React state and use setState function.
Look here for more information: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I'm already doing this. Look at the remove function: the "impacts" is my array with the informations. The second array called array is just to exclude the line that I needed to exclude.

Comment: Isn't that this.remove? Your onClick is calling remove, but it's a react component so remove is a method

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var index = e.target.value;
 impacts.splice(index, 1);
 setImpacts([...impacts]);
```